# In oc project to import swift file by cocoapods , *-Swift.h not found

Tags: ios, swift

I met a question, my project was created by oc , then I import a swift file by cocoapods , and I set Defines Module . In normal , It will have a *-Swift.h by created by default, but when I import *-Swift.h to project, It will tell me file not found, but if I not use cocoapods import file , it will not have this question. who can tell me why ? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a module import like:

```
@import Alamofire;
```